# NullPointerException in MQQueueConnectionFactory object creation

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am getting the below error on instantiating MQConnectionFactory() object using com.ibm.mq.jar using v8.0.0.4.While the same is working fine in com.ibm.mq.jar v6.0.0.1.

Maintain ThreadPool size     :-  false
|   Maximum ThreadPool size      :-  -1
|   ThreadPool inactive timeout  :-  0
|   unavailable -                :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:170)
>       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:167)
>       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.(MQConnectionFactory.java:271)
>       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:72)
>       at com.SendMessage.putToQueue(SendMessage.java:66)
>       at com.SendMessage.main(SendMessage.java:123)

```
//Sending the certs
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\trustStore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\keyStore.jks");
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings","false");

//Check for JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files 
int maxKeyLen = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
System.out.println(maxKeyLen);

host = s;
channel = s1;
port = j;
requestQ = s2;
factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
factory.setTransportType(mqClient);
factory.setQueueManager(qmgr);
factory.setHostName(host);
factory.setChannel(channel);
factory.setPort(port);


//Use this for SSL ciphersuites 
factory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA");

connection = factory.createQueueConnection();

session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

int i = 1;
sQueue = new MQQueue();
sQueue.setBaseQueueName(requestQ);
sQueue.setPersistence(-1);
sQueue.setExpiry(0L);
sQueue.setTargetClient(i);
sQueue.setPriority(5);

outTextMessage = session.createTextMessage();
outTextMessage.setText(s3);


sender = session.createSender(sQueue);

sender.send(outTextMessage);
msgId = outTextMessage.getJMSMessageID();
System.out.println(msgId);

sender.close();

session.close();

connection.close();
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @Roger..Posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
host = s; 
channel = s1; 
port = j; 
requestQ = s2;
```

This is weird and bad coding, in my opinion.  You did not give me all of the code but rather a snippet but I can guess that it is from a method called putToQueue().  Therefore, you should be naming your variables for invocation to be the correct names rather than doing that piece of useless coding.

```
sQueue.setExpiry(0L);
```

Do you understand what this means?  This say to expire the message in zero milliseconds!!!!  In other words, the message basically expires the moment you put it to the queue.  Kinda of pointless.  If you want unlimited then either remove that line or use "-1L" (i.e. CMQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED).

```
sQueue.setPersistence(-1);
```

Again, you do not understand the meaning of the value.  "-1" means use parent persistent value for a topic.  You should use 0 for not persistent (CMQC.MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT) or 1 for persistent (CMQC.MQPER_PERSISTENT).

```
connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
```

OMG.  Can you at least "pretend" to understand security and set the UserID and Password on the createQueueConnection() method call.

Finally, where is your start() method for the connection?

i.e.

```
connection = factory.createQueueConnection(userId, password);
connection.start();
```

Comment: The code I gave above is just a Proof of concept. I will certainly change my code to the standards later. I dont mind the security or expiry of my messages. I wanted to check if I can able to establish the connection and send some messages. The question here is "connection = factory.createQueueConnection();" is working in MQ v6 jar but the same is not working in v8.0.0.4 jar. I think its more around the cipher suites.If you have any observations on that please let me know.

Comment: Fix the other problems, especially the missing start method and then worry about SSL/TLS stuff.

Comment: I am unable to create connection object without which I cannot start connection. The exception is thrown at connection = factory.createQueueConnection(userId, password);